# How to play a video in landscape mode but app support only portrait mode?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiwebview, orientation

I am making a application which support only Portrait mode.here iam loading youtube videos in uiwebview. so when i switch to landscape mode video has to play in landscape mode also. But after taping  on done of  videoplayer. my view controller is changing to landscape mode but it has be in portrait mode only here is my webview code

```
         web=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(2,0, 140, 99)];
          web.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
        [web setDataDetectorTypes: UIDataDetectorTypeNone];

        NSString *embedHTML = @"<iframe title=\"YouTube video player\" width=\"320\" height=\"460\" scrolling=\"no\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/%@?modestbranding=1&amp;rel=0;autoplay=1;showinfo=0;loop=1;autohide=1\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen allowTransparency=\"true\"></iframe>";

        NSString *htmlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, [youtubeId_array objectAtIndex:i]];              
         web.tag=i+100;
        web.scrollView.bounces=NO;
        [web loadHTMLString:htmlStr baseURL:nil];
        [view addSubview:web];

  -(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    return ( toInterfaceOrientation=UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set `rootViewController` to `self` when you returning to the app?

In your viewcontroller:

```
import "AppDelegate.h"
...
- (void)functionRunWhenVideoFinish {
    ...
    self.appDelegate.window.rootViewController = self;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Sorry, iam not able to understand  what u r saying?

Comment: when you returning to your app from youtube one, in the method in your view controller that will be fire, try to set the root view controller of your app to that viewcontroller.

First in the view controller import the AppDelegate.h, then add a property like this @property (retain,nonatomic) ALCAppDelegate *appDelegate;

finally add self.appDelegate.window.rootViewController = self; to your code

Answer (score 0):

**Add These Lines in Appdelegate and your Required View Controller**

while clicking done button app will move required orientation.

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO; 
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    //LandScapeMode:- UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
    //PortraitMode:- 
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait 
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    //LandScapeMode:- UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
   // ProtraitMode:-
   return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait
}
```